# Cumulative sum whose calculation is conditionally based on previous value - Postgres Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum

I would like to do a running sum calculation, where the calculation for the value of the current row depends on the cumulative sum of the previous row.

| userid | transaction_type | amount | cumulative_sum_sell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Sell** | $134,438 | $134,438 |
| 1 | *Buy* | $130,011 | $4,427 |
| 1 | Cash Deposit | $4,000 | $4,427 |
| 1 | Cash Deposit | $800 | $4,427 |
| 1 | Cash Deposit | $2,000 | $4,427 |
| 1 | *Buy* | $10,000 | **$4,427** |

For the column "cumulative_sum_sell", I want to take the cumulative sum per userid (ordered by date which I don't have here) with the following calculations:

sum(
if transaction_type = Sell then amount
if transaction_type = Buy AND THE CUMULATIVE SUM OF PREVIOUS ROW is greater than or equal to the amount then -amount
)

I can't get my code to do the calculation based on what the cumulative sum of the previous column is compared to the value amount from the current row. Right now I have it as
    `case when transactiontype = 'Sell' then amount when transactiontype = 'Buy' then case when amount <= **MISSING PIECE** then -amount`

Thank you!

Comment: [Recursive solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/IcPGNZUG) is possible if allowed.

Comment: Add date field (could be dummy data) other userid rows and expected result of your query over the sample data. Seems a case for [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: Is $4,427 the correct `cummulative_summ_sell` in that last sample output? It seem's like it should be either -$5,573 or $0.

Comment: @JohnH since $10,000 is greater than the cumulative sum of the previous row ($4,427), we do not subtract the amount, therefore, it remains $4,427

Comment: @PepeNO the expected result is what I have in the cumulative_sum_sell column, The date is not as important as the task of being able to refer to the same column you are calculating

Comment: @PonderStibbons, thank you, after learning more about recursive CTEs, I think this could be the solution. I keep on getting an error on redshift saying "Recursive CTE must not omit column names", I've tried many ways but I can't seem to debug this error

Comment: This (probably) means, that you have to define column names like in lines 1 and 5 in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fu_0biv1).